# Force using orderByWithPrefix() in a query list with JOIN

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I'm using succesfully Backpack v.4.1 in a Laravel 8 project.
Unfortunally, our client provides us an external Oracle db, not originally supported by Backpack.
Thanks to [yajra/laravel-oci8](https://packagist.org/packages/yajra/laravel-oci8) package everythings works fine.

The only thing I need is to force to use `orderByWithPrefix()` function for the `ListOperation` trait when a join is necessary.
It can be used only if the database driver belongs to the array `getSqlDriverList()` (in file `vendor/backpack/crud/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/CrudPanel.php`:162):

```
    /**
     * Get SQL driver list.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSqlDriverList()
    {
        return ['mysql', 'sqlsrv', 'sqlite', 'pgsql'];
    }
```

For my project, in order to work, I've changed the Query trait in this way (removing also the useless `getSqlDriverList()` function):

```
diff --git a/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/Query.php b/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/Query.php
index 8a7453a1..ad802b97 100644
--- a/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/Query.php
+++ b/src/app/Library/CrudPanel/Traits/Query.php
@@ -145,7 +145,7 @@ trait Query
 
     public function orderByWithPrefix($column_name, $column_direction = 'ASC')
     {
-        if ($this->driverIsSql()) {
+        if (null !== $this->query->getQuery()->joins) {
             return $this->query->orderByRaw($this->model->getTableWithPrefix().'.'.$column_name.' '.$column_direction);
         }
```

There is a better solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Huh... actually makes a lot of sense  Don't know how we didn't think of that, thanks robdex. I've just opened https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/3555 to talk about doing the same thing inside the Backpack core.

Comment: And to answer your question - personally I think it's a good solution 